# Where to find System Image to create a Virtual Device in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0, android-virtual-device, avd-manager

I want to test my application in Xiomi RedMi Note 4. For that, I want to create a virtual device in my Android Studio.

I know how to create a virtual device in AVD manager. 
Apparently, AVD manager gives us two option when we want to create a new Hardware Configuration

- New Hardware Profile
- Import Hardware profile

[image]

New Hardware profile opens a Configuration page where we can create a new Virtual device where we can give name, default skin, RAM, Sensors etc. I know this.
But my question is related to the second option which is **Import Hardware profile**. We can upload XML file from the desktop using this option. How to download those XML files for any specific vendor. 
Can anyone streamline the process for me?

Comment: did you get a profile or did you create one op ? I'm trying to do something similar right now.

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not. I had to test with physical device :( @himanshuxd

Comment: Hah makes sense, I've created a minimal avd for my Xiaomi using the screen size and resolution and android version params, I too am currently using the Physical device for testing, but when the pushed apk will corrupt the existing one we never know. Thanks though !

Comment: I was working with wifi scan functionality. So one thing I found was that the XIOMI phone does not send the broadcast as often as the other devices send (Google Pixel for eg). I wanted to replicate that. But yeah. If you ever find a solution. Post-it in the answer section. Might as well help the others in the future. @himanshuxd

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be very experienced in hardware/ electronics to create a hardware profile.

When i wanted to test my application on different versions of Samsung phones, i imported the hardware profiles from their website: as an example check the link below, you can download a zip file and then upload to android studio.

https://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000287

But to actually create a hardware profile, it is not efficiently possible, yet possible, but i do not recommend it, if you want a particular phone, go to their website and install their packages.

Comment: I do not find anywhere for Xiomi

Comment: The link in the answer does not have any results for hardware profiles. But while searching the Samsung Developer site, I found a Test Lab that could be useful to someone:
https://developer.samsung.com/remotetestlab/rtlDeviceList.action

Comment: The first link (v=T000000287) is now a dead end.

Comment: @RohitSingh  I think you mean `Xaomi` ?   I am also looking for same.

Comment: Yes, @javadba. I found emulators for Samsung devices https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy-emulator-skin/guide.html but not for Xiomi :(